# C++ "call of overloaded is ambiguous" in FA

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm working with firefly algorith implementation in C++ and I have a little problem. Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define DUMP        1
#define MAX_FFA        1000
#define MAX_D        1000

using namespace std;

int D = 1000;                        // dimension of the problem
int n = 20;                        // number of fireflies
int MaxGeneration;                // number of iterations
int NumEval;                        // number of evaluations
int Index[MAX_FFA];                // sort of fireflies according to fitness values

double ffa[MAX_FFA][MAX_D];        // firefly agents
double ffa_tmp[MAX_FFA][MAX_D]; // intermediate population
double f[MAX_FFA];                // fitness values
double I[MAX_FFA];                // light intensity
double nbest[MAX_FFA];          // the best solution found so far
double lb[MAX_D];                // upper bound
double ub[MAX_D];                // lower bound

double alpha = 0.5;                // alpha parameter
double betamin = 0.2;           // beta parameter
double gama = 1.0;                // gamma parameter

double fbest;                        // the best objective function

typedef double (*FunctionCallback)(double sol[MAX_D]);

/*benchmark functions */
double cost(double sol[MAX_D]);
double sphere(double sol[MAX_D]);

/*Write your own objective function */
FunctionCallback function = &cost;

// optionally recalculate the new alpha value
double alpha_new(double alpha, int NGen)
{
        double delta;                        // delta parameter
        delta = 1.0-pow((pow(10.0, -4.0)/0.9), 1.0/(double) NGen);
        return (1-delta)*alpha;
}

// initialize the firefly population
void init_ffa()
{
        int i, j;
        double r;

        // initialize upper and lower bounds
        for (i=0;i<D;i++)
        {
                lb[i] = 0.0;
                ub[i] = 2.0;
        }

        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                for (j=0;j<D;j++)
                {
                        r = (   (double)rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX)+(double)(1)) );
                        ffa[i][j]=r*(ub[i]-lb[i])+lb[i];
                }
                f[i] = 1.0;                        // initialize attractiveness
                I[i] = f[i];
        }
}

// implementation of bubble sort
void sort_ffa()
{
        int i, j;

        // initialization of indexes
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                Index[i] = i;

        // Bubble sort
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
                for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
                {
                        if(I[i] > I[j])
                        {
                                double z = I[i];        // exchange attractiveness
                                I[i] = I[j];
                                I[j] = z;
                                z = f[i];                        // exchange fitness
                                f[i] = f[j];
                                f[j] = z;
                                int k = Index[i];        // exchange indexes
                                Index[i] = Index[j];
                                Index[j] = k;
                        }
                }
        }
}

// replace the old population according the new Index values
void replace_ffa()
{
        int i, j;

        // copy original population to temporary area
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<D;j++)
                {
                        ffa_tmp[i][j] = ffa[i][j];
                }
        }

        // generational selection in sense of EA
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<D;j++)
                {
                        ffa[i][j] = ffa_tmp[Index[i]][j];
                }
        }
}

void findlimits(int k)
{
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<D;i++)
        {
                if(ffa[k][i] < lb[i])
                        ffa[k][i] = lb[i];
                if(ffa[k][i] > ub[i])
                        ffa[k][i] = ub[i];
        }
}

void move_ffa()
{
        int i, j, k;
        double scale;
        double r, beta;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                scale = abs(ub[i]-lb[i]);
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                        r = 0.0;
                        for(k=0;k<D;k++)
                        {
                                r += (ffa[i][k]-ffa[j][k])*(ffa[i][k]-ffa[j][k]);
                        }
                        r = sqrt(r);
                        if(I[i] > I[j])        // brighter and more attractive
                        {
                                double beta0 = 1.0;
                                beta = (beta0-betamin)*exp(-gama*pow(r, 2.0))+betamin;
                                for(k=0;k<D;k++)
                                {
                                        r = (   (double)rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX)+(double)(1)) );
                                        double tmpf = alpha*(r-0.5)*scale;
                                        ffa[i][k] = ffa[i][k]*(1.0-beta)+ffa_tmp[j][k]*beta+tmpf;
                                }
                        }
                }
                findlimits(i);
        }
}

void dump_ffa(int gen)
{
        cout << "Dump at gen= " << gen << " best= " << fbest << endl;
}

/* display syntax messages */
void help()
{
        cout << "Syntax:" << endl;
        cout << "  Firefly [-h|-?] [-l] [-p] [-c] [-k] [-s] [-t]" << endl;
        cout << "    Parameters: -h|-? = command syntax" << endl;
        cout << "                                 -n = number of fireflies" << endl;
        cout << "                                 -d = problem dimension" << endl;
        cout << "                                 -g = number of generations" << endl;
        cout << "                                 -a = alpha parameter" << endl;
        cout << "                                 -b = beta0 parameter" << endl;
        cout << "                                 -c = gamma parameter" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int i;
        int t = 1;                // generation  counter

         // interactive parameters handling
         for(int i=1;i<argc;i++)
         {
            if((strncmp(argv[i], "-h", 2) == 0) || (strncmp(argv[i], "-?", 2) == 0))
            {
                    help();
                    return 0;
            }
            else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-n", 2) == 0)         // number of fireflies
            {
                    n = atoi(&argv[i][2]);
            }
            else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-d", 2) == 0)                // problem dimension
            {
                    D = atoi(&argv[i][2]);
            }
            else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-g", 2) == 0)                // number of generations
            {
                    MaxGeneration = atoi(&argv[i][2]);
            }
            else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-a", 2) == 0)                // alpha parameter
            {
                    alpha = atof(&argv[i][2]);
            }
            else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-b", 2) == 0)                // beta parameter
            {
                    betamin = atof(&argv[i][2]);
            }
            else if(strncmp(argv[i], "-c", 2) == 0)                // gamma parameter
            {
                    gama = atof(&argv[i][2]);
            }
            else
            {
                    cerr << "Fatal error: invalid parameter: " << argv[i] << endl;
                    return -1;
            }
        }

        // firefly algorithm optimization loop
        // determine the starting point of random generator
        srand(1);

        // generating the initial locations of n fireflies
        init_ffa();
#ifdef DUMP
        dump_ffa(t);
#endif

        while(t <= MaxGeneration)
        {
                // this line of reducing alpha is optional
                alpha = alpha_new(alpha, MaxGeneration);

                // evaluate new solutions
                for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                        f[i] = function(ffa[i]);                        // obtain fitness of solution
                        I[i] = f[i];                                        // initialize attractiveness
                }

                // ranking fireflies by their light intensity
                sort_ffa();
                // replace old population
                replace_ffa();

                // find the current best
                for(i=0;i<D;i++)
                        nbest[i] = ffa[0][i];
                fbest = I[0];

                // move all fireflies to the better locations
                move_ffa();
#ifdef DUMP
                dump_ffa(t);
#endif
                t++;
        }

        cout << "End of optimization: fbest = " << fbest << endl;

        return 0;
}

// FF test function
double cost(double* sol)
{
        double sum = 0.0;

        for(int i=0;i<D;i++)
                sum += (sol[i]-1)*(sol[i]-1);

        return sum;
}

double sphere(double* sol) {
        int j;
        double top = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < D; j++) {
                top = top + sol[j] * sol[j];
        }
        return top;
}
```

In line 171 there is problem "call of overloaded is ambiguous". I try to find solution, but I found nothing. Anyone have a idea how to fix it?

The line is:

```
scale = abs(ub[i]-lb[i]);
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Perhaps you could reduce it to a small example that still causes the problem? There's a good chance that you'll discover the problem yourself when you do that; and if you don't, more people will be willing to investigate.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: @Blender: The one just below 170 :-P (sorry I couldn't resist...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problmatic line is:

```
scale = abs(ub[i]-lb[i]);
```

To solve, just include `<cmath>` instead of `math.h` to bring the overloaded `abs` for `double`.

```
#include <cmath>
```

Otherwise you have old-C style `abs` which is made for integers. If you don't want include `cmath` then use `fabs` instead.